# C# Can it solve polynomial equations?

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

For example, i'm trying to solve

```
((x-4)^2 + (y-1)^2) - ((x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2) = 9
```

the answer is: `y = 4`

However, how do i use C# to solve this?

Ultimately, the program i'm trying to build uses 2 known points to find a missing 3D point, by hand i got this answered, it's just that i don't know how C# handles things like 3x + 2x, etc. but there has to be way otherwise how do we have graphics in computers? graphics uses a lot of trigonometry i assume.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int y = 3x - 2x;
}
```

Comment: What you have there is a polynomial. Not an equation. There's no equals sign.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-4%29%5E2+%2B+%28y-1%29%5E2%29+-+%28%28x-4%29%5E2+%2B+%28y-4%29%5E2%29+%3D+9

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a math problem

Comment: @AdanRamirez You've been downvoted because you demonstrate no research being done on the problem, nor do you show even a basic understanding of how programming works.

Comment: @AdanRamirez Yeah, using professional tooling which is the result of decades of research and thousands of man-hours. What you're asking for quite simply is not as easy as you think.

Comment: You are using "math-like" syntax in c# code. `int y = 3x - 2x;` won't even compile. c# is not a _math language_.  Now you _can_ solve mathematical problems in many languages, even c#, but you'll need to take that mathematical idea and translate it into something that c# can understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an impossible problem, but it isn't easy either. You're talking about writing a program to do *algebra* -- not a program to compute an equation but to symbolically manipulate the equation to solve it for an answer (or set of answers).

You might be interested in this: 
[CodeProject: Computer Algebra System for .NET Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/604792/Computer-Algebra-System-for-NET-Framework)

Answer (score 0):

No. C# doesn't know what `3x` and `2x` are in your code. If you want to solve an equation, you have to program each individual step of it.

Comment: @AdanRamirez What you're asking is not trivial. Look into parsers and lexxers (for example ANTLR) to start with.